# Hide referrer header from 3rd party website

Tags: https, security-certificate, referrer

Right now my site uses http and has many links to one other website (say https://instagram.com). I would prefer they not see that clicks come from my site.

I also do not want https to be seen anywhere on the website. So this is what I'm planning to do:

- Buy a SSL certificate
- Create https://example.com/redir.php?url=foo (which does
  the actual redirect)
- Create http://example.com/redir.html?url=foo (which will
  contain redir.php as an iframe)
- When user clicks a link they're taken
  to http://example.com/redir.html and they don't see that https is being used
- The destination site uses 100% https. And all their http pages are (301 or 302) redirects to the https page. So I link to their http pages, not https

My questions are:

1. Will the http referrer be stripped all the time? I do not want them to see that the clicks are coming from my site 100% of the time (not 99.99%)
2. In the redirect file, will using a (https) frame inside (http) html work?
3. I need https only for redirect.php, so can I continue to use http everywhere on my site?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033300/stop-link-from-sending-referrer-to-destination

Comment: That answers question no. 1. What about 2 and 3?

Comment: Why not redirect the entire site to SSL? Why use an iframe? The content shouldn't change nor should the links. Therefore just implement a server-side redirect.